# Splitting load of an API between multiple servers

Tags: node.js, api, express, server, endpoint

I'm planning to build an API for one of my projects. But I'm looking for a good way to manage it, and manage server load.

Would I be better off just creating everything on one server, or should I create multiple?

Thoughts:

If I create one server and that server crashes, the whole system would go down. But if I create multiple servers to handle this, and one of them crashes, only that part would go down.

How I was thinking to accomplish this:

1) Create one API ENDPOINT

2) When a user sends a REQUEST to that API ENDPOINT, the ENDPOINT would send another request to the correct server containing the special task, when the task is done it would return the data back to the user.

AKA:

User => ENDPOINT => ENDPOINT 1, ENDPOINT 2, ENDPOINT 3, => ENDPOINT => User

Is this how I should do it?

P.S. I don't know if this the right terminology but I'm trying to learn how to scale my ENDPOINTS/API/code.

Comment: better you have look at microservice it gives the flexibility of work multiple server.
https://microservices.io/

Comment: Aim to simplify the app/api depoyment so you can easily depoy it on anything like docker, lxd image, git deployment, now.sh etc etc, then all you need is a reverse proxy in front like nginx which can proxy all the requests to the upstream servers, if one goes down it will failover, though you also need to think about abstracting db if your using one like mysql etc, that would also need a deployment/backup and load balancing strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the load balancer, you should use **specific web server applications** to do that, **like `nginx`or `apache`**. This kind of web server tools already have implemented load balance mechanisms, you just need to configure it.

Also, I recommend you to **pack your server** in `docker` images. This way you could use Docker Swarm or Kubernetes to deploy and scale up/down your application. It's easier to manage your services, check applications states and deploy new versions.

You could use `docker` with `nginx`, where each docker container has an instance of your application and `nginx` will take care of redirect/distribute your requests between your instances.

Answer (score 0):

What you are basically looking for is a comparison between microservices based architecture (or SOA) and a monolith.

In microservices, there are multiple services performing specific tasks. They all in-turn are used to perform complex tasks. Monoliths on the other hand consist of a big server which does everything and is also the single point of failure like your pointed.

### Should you move to microservices?

It is widely agreed that a project should be built in monolithic architecture and then moved to microservices as the complexity grows. [Martin Fowler's article](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html) explains this concept well.

This is because there are certain disadvantages and tradeoffs associated with this architecture -- inconsistency and latency, for instance.

**TLDR;** Stick to one server if starting, break into services when it becomes complex.